# Python OpenCV HoughLinesP Inaccurate Line Detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, houghlinesp

Consider three points A, B, C in an image.

[image]

Below are their coordinates in the image of size 300x300.

[image]

I am trying to detect and draw a line connecting through these three points using below HoughLinesP code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #Convert img to grayscale 
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=1, minLineLength=5, maxLineGap=10)
print(lines)

for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 1)
cv2.imshow("result", img)
```

But it detects a line that passes through only B and C. Why is it so?

```
Output:
[[[110 100 120 100]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Increase the Accumulator's Resolution by giving much smaller values 
  for rho and theta.
- Set Accumulator's threshold to minimum 2.

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho=0.1, theta=np.pi/180 * 0.1, threshold=2, minLineLength=5, maxLineGap=10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`cv2.HoughLinesP()` is mainly used for detecting a line, not really used for drawing. To draw a line given your three points, there are a few other options you can try. The first method is to filter the points by finding the leftmost and rightmost points then drawing the line with `cv2.line()`. Another approach is to find all the points then use `cv2.fillPoly()`. A third method is to use [`cv2.polylines()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines)

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(gray > 0))
coords = np.rot90(coords, 2)
cv2.fillPoly(image, [coords], (36,255,12)) # or
# cv2.polylines(image, [coords], 1, (36,255,12))

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: HoughLinesP is mainly used for detecting lines, in your image you have three points instead of a line. Maybe after filling the points to create a line then you can use HoughLinesP

Comment: Thank you. This dots and image is for just to understand the working of HoughLinesP with threshold parameter. And I believe it works by joining points (not only lines) that appears in straight line.

Comment: HoughLinesP worked after increasing the Accumulator's resolution and threshold.